# PHP : echo-ing minus values without the minsus sign

Tags: php

I have a negative float result from some money calculation, something like - 0,01 $.
Now I want to display this result without the minus sign just like this 0,01 $.
Is there an easy way to display a `-` value without the `-` sign ?

Comment: The function abs?

Comment: `0,01 $` ... that's a really peculiar currency format; it looks like French but with a dollar sign.

Comment: you may ignore the dollar sign and focus on the number, then you do not need to wonder ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `abs`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php

```
echo abs($yourVariable);
```